# Ruby on rails - convertion of bootstrap datepicker value to ruby time value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my form view I use bootstrap daytime picker

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="select date you want to send" class="form-control" name="send_date" id="datetimepicker" />

<script>

$.datetimepicker.setLocale('<%= session[:locale] %>');

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
minDate: 0,
dayOfWeekStart : 1,
lang:'<%= session[:locale] %>',
startDate: '-0m',
format:'d-m-Y H:i:s',
});
</script>
```

In my SMS controller:

```
    def send_sms
       message = params[:message]
       number = params[:number]
       send_date = params[:send_date]

       format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC"
       send_date = DateTime.strptime(send_date, format)

       SendSmsTimeJob.set(wait_until: send_date).perform_later(number, message)

        flash[:success] = "mesaj gitti"
        redirect_to current_user 
    end
```

When I submit the form it says:

> ```
> ArgumentError in SmsController#send_sms
> invalid date
> ```

I think that problem is I cannot convert input value to ruby time value? How can I overcome with this?

Comment: Can you please paste the params your SMSController receives from the server log?

Comment: `Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"tbgU6SHQ2Fl+8wPLHb0+p2r9OCvY5PZLyTBrIvLIm7ulWqZoveHz+QZLoYvPbdPMhxI30yUlwiOPaZD3UU+8RQ==",
 "number"=>"",
 "message"=>"",
 "send_date"=>"07-03-2016 14:00:17"}`

Comment: See the answer by Rubysmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your format to this.

```
format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your datepicker you format your date as `format:'d-m-Y H:i:s'` which means days-month-years

In your ruby code you parse it differently:

`format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC"`

First you have the date order reversed: year-month-days
Second you add another expected value 'UTC' which is not included in the string you are trying to parse.

Change your format to `format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"` as suggested by Rubysmith

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Date.parse params[:send_date]` instead.

Comment: I tried 
send_date = Date.parse params[:send_date]
SendSmsTimeJob.set(wait_until: send_date).perform_later(number, message)
It gives me:
undefined method `to_f' for Mon, 07 Mar 2016:Date

Comment: is SendSmsTimeJob.set function defined by you? If so, can you show the content of the method?